# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'fetch' called on an object that does not implement interface Window

Tags: javascript, fetch, svelte, extends

I'm getting an error when using `fetch` passed into constructor in a javascript class:

```
import { browser } from '$app/env';

class Api {
    constructor(fetch) {
        this.req = fetch;
    }

    async api(path, body = {}, opts = {}) {
        path = import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT + path;
        body = JSON.stringify(body);
        const method = opts.method || 'GET';
        const headers = {};

        if (browser) {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            headers.Authorization = token ? 'Bearer ' + token : '';
        }

        const res = await this.req(path, {
            method: opts.method || 'GET',
            body: method === 'GET' ? null : body,
            headers
        });

        if (res.ok) {
            return await (opts.raw ? res.text() : res.json());
        }

        throw res;
    }
}

export default Api;
```

```
import Api from './create-api';

class Jobs extends Api {
    constructor(fetch) {
        super(fetch);
    }

    async getAll() {
        return await this.api('/jobs');
    }
}

export default Jobs;
```

Using it in svelte kit with `await new Jobs(fetch).getAll()`

Comment: @Phil the auto-binding made by `addEventListener` is even more tedious, not sure this is the best dupe target for this question. (though I couldn't find a better one myself just yet)

Comment: @Kaiido agreed. At its core it's the same issue, just the process of getting there is different. The solutions however are the same

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen this specific error, but here's what I think is happening:

When you invoke a method on an object in javascript the scope within that method (what `this` points to) is bound to the object.

Because you're invoking fetch as a method on your `Api` instance, `this` likely points to the instance instead of `window`.

Something in the implementation of fetch expects `this` to be an instance of Window, hence the error.

I think you could solve this by either:

1. making it an arrow function that just passes the arguments through to fetch:

```
this.req = (...args) => fetch(...args)
```

or 2) explicitly binding fetch to `window` (or `global` or whatever):

```
await new Jobs(fetch.bind(window)).getAll()
```

Comment: `window` does not exist when doing ssr in sveltekit.

Comment: That’s why I said “or `global`”.

Comment: I did this and it works: `this.fetch = browser ? fetch.bind(window) : fetch;` in the constructor. I think sveltekit ssr version of fetch already is bound to window or global